# tftp-hpa only works when restart

Tags: tftp

I am running tftp-hpa server which was installed as shown below on Ubuntu 15.04

```
sudo apt-get install tftpd-hpa
```

The configuration file name tftp-hpa is located in `/etc/defaults` as shown

```
 # /etc/default/tftpd-hpa
RUN_DAEMON="yes"
TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/var/lib/tftpboot"
TFTP_ADDRESS="[::]:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"
```

The problem is that I can transfer files from `/var/lib/tftpboot` only once. In order to perform further transfer I have to issue the restart on the server as follows.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tftpd-hpa restart
```

Failure to issue above command means that the tftpd server no longer respond to any tftp client request.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I see the same on Ubuntu 15.04. My workaround is to explicitly specify the server IP. For example, 192.168.0.2 instead of [::] in the /etc/default/tftpd-hpa configuration file:

```
RUN_DAEMON="yes"
TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/tftpboot"
#TFTP_ADDRESS="[::]:69"
TFTP_ADDRESS="192.168.0.2:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure --create"
```

Then it gets the file every time. No need to restart.